# How to pass dynamic variables in firebase database set command?

Tags: bash, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, command-line-interface, firebase-cli

I want to update the build version number at the firebase, so I am running a firebase command through a bash file that looks like this-

```
sudo firebase database:set /build_version --data '"1.1.13.12.34"' --project <PROJECT_ID>
```

This is working fine.

But, I want to pass the version number dynamically, so I would like to write this command something like that-

```
VERSION=<ANY_NUMBER>
sudo firebase database:set /build_version --data $VERSION --project <PROJECT_ID>
```

But passing dynamic variable giving me an error-

> Error: Unexpected error while setting data: FirebaseError: HTTP Error:
> 400, Invalid data; couldn't parse JSON object, array, or value.

I have read that [firebase doesn't allow some special character](https://zapier.com/help/doc/common-problems-firebase) and [we cannot wrap firebase data in double-quotes](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/12/read-and-write-your-realtime-database.html)

At firebase, "build_version" is not a JSON Object. It's a single variable.
My real-time database structure is looking like this-

[image]

Can anyone suggest how can I pass the dynamic data to the firebase database command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sharing just a trick

If firebase doesn't allow using special characters then you can just put any string (let's say BUILD_VERSION) instead of your shell script variable $VERSION and then using shell script syntax **just search and replace that string** with your build version before running firebase command.
In the end, you can again replace the build version with the string BUILD_VERSION.